# How to get value of selected radiobuttonlist item

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

How to get selected radiobutton value from below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string query="select top 0.1 percent Title, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 from [Question] order by newid()" ;
     SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
     con.Open();
     SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if(dr.Read())
     {
         rbList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
         rbList1.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
         rbList1.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());
         rbList1.Items.Add(dr[3].ToString());
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Some Proble Occure !");
     }
     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Err, what? Explain what your issue is, because it doesn't help to simply dump the code without telling us anything about what you're trying to, what problems you're experiencing, and what should be happening!

Comment: What have you tried? The documentation is generally a good place to start... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx

Comment: `rbList1.SelectedItem`

Answer (score 1):

Try these

`rbList1.SelectedIndex // Gets the index of the currently selected item`

`rbList1.SelectedItem // Gets the currently selected item`

`rbList1.SelectedValue // Gets the value of the currently selected item`

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions first:

- Don't databind the `RadioButtonList` from `Page_Load` on every postback, check the `IsPostBack` property, otherwise events aren't triggered and you won't get the the selected item
- Use the `using`-statement for anything implementing `IDisposable`, especially in System.Data namespace to ensure that all unmanaged resources(like connections) are disposed/closed
- Use th appropriate methods of `DbDatareader` like `GetInt` or `GetString` instead of using `ToString` for all(which also throws an exception if the field is null)

---

```
string query = "select top 0.1 percent Title, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4 from [Question] order by newid()";
using (var con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
             rbList1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
             rbList1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1));
             rbList1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(2));
             rbList1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(3));
        }
    }
}
```

---

To your problem: i have no idea since you haven't mentioned the actual problem.

> How to get selected radiobutton value from below code

Then handle the `RadioButtonList`'s [`SelectedIndexChanged`-event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx).